# How to get Xamarin Studio C# output within the IDE?

Tags: c#, mono, ide, xamarin

I recently started experimenting with Xamarin and Mono C# on my Mac. I am used to working on Windows with Visual Studio so I find it cumbersome when every time I run my console application, a new terminal window and mono compiler terminal  open up. And I have to manually close them. Is there anyway to get the output of my programs from a window or pane *inside* the IDE ? Or is there anyway to set it up so only one terminal window shows up ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the Project Options there is a **Run on external console** check box in the **Run** - **General** category which controls this behaviour. If you uncheck this option when you run a console application the output will be shown in an Application Output window inside Xamarin Studio and no external console window will be opened.

Comment: Some precisions for those who don't find: as terryogara said, to open the Project Options, you can select Project > [ProjectName] Options in the top-bar, but you need to make sure that you are selecting your project (or any folder/file inside) in the Solution panel. Selecting the solution won't work, be careful as the project may share the same name. You can also right-click on the Project name in the Solution panel and select Options. In the Project Options, select Run > Configurations > Default in the left panel, then in the General tab, uncheck Run on external console.

Comment: You'll also want to open the Output panel (bottom at the bottom right of the editor) and pin it so that the console does not close immediately at the end of your Main, if you need to check some output. Using Console.ReadLine(); or Console.ReadKey(); is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else arriving at this question who can't locate 'Project Options', the item is found in a drop down menu under the Project Tab (located at the top of the screen on the app's main nav bar). When a solution/file is loaded, the item is listed with your project's actual name, ex: 'MyProject Options' or 'MyProject&Options' (–it does not literally read 'Project Options').