# Console in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, console

Background: I was working on a C# project. In the past, when I did

> System.Console.WriteLine("Hello");

I would get see a pop-up Console printing "Hello". The console disappeared today, what can I do to make it appear again?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI: I'm using Xamarin on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Visual studio**, go to the menu options and the choose:

Debug --> Windows --> Output.

Then make sure the window is set to 'show Output from: **Debug**'

If you are using **Xamarin studio**, first of all enable the Application Output window:

View -> Pads -> Application Output

Comment: Thank you, IdoT, I'm using Xamarin on my mac.

Comment: Thanks, again. Didn't see the "Hello World" message even though I looked into Application Output. Any hints?

Comment: It is probably printed in the terminal. check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28602909/2452682

Answer (score 1):

Right click (on project) -> Options -> Run -> General

1. Run on external console (if checked, will open terminal, otherwise outputs to Application Output window)
2. Pause console output (if checked, will require a keypress to continue)

Comment: Thank you, SKall, I tried this but the console still didn't show. Guess it's a bug.

Comment: I can confirm that for Windows+XS 5.10 it works, thank you SKall.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your answers, I really appreciate it.

Here're the solutions that worked for me.

### SOLUTION ONE

Check the "Start Debugging" under "Run". If it's greyed out, then right click on your project and click "Set as Startup Project". After doing this you should be able to see a normal "Start Debugging" in black. Click on that and the console should be there for you!

If Solution One doesn't work, try this.

### SOLUTION TWO

1. Go to the Solution file and delete all files ending with   *.userpref_(hh:mm:ss) (note that the hh:mm:ss is the time the file was created)
2. Compile
3. After you compile, you'll see exclamation marks next to your projects and the project titles in grey. When you mouse over them, you'll see 'not build in active configuration'.
4. Then right click on your project, choose 'Options'
5. Go to Configurations under 'Build'
6. Check all boxes under 'Build' and compile again.
7. Build All (under the Build Tab on top).

*Steps 4-6 were suggested by this webpage:
http://crossplatform.io/2013/12/02/setting-the-active-configuration-in-xamarin-studio/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Xamarin IDE, here is the way out that worked for me (I couldn't see the above mentioned options):

`Run -> Run with -> Custom Configuration...`

In the dialog window that opens, uncheck the "Run on external console" option. You're now done with your setting.

On the down-side: I'll have to do this every time I want to Run :(

Note: I didn't find a way yet to save this config for future Runs.